# how to highlight navigation bar while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this basic HTML code which has sections, and then I created a basic navigation bar dynamically by javaScript

```
function buildNav() {
    for (section of sections) {
        let item = document.createElement("li");

        item.innerHTML = `<a data-nav="${section.id}">${section.dataset.nav}</a>`;
        item.classList.add("item");
}
        navBar.appendChild(item);
        
    }
}
```

and I used this function to add active class to each section

```
function isInView(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.top >= -70 && rect.top <= 300;
};

function addActive() {
    document.addEventListener(
        "scroll",
        () => {

            for (section of sections) {
                if(isInView(section)){
                    section.classList.add('active')
                }else{section.classList.remove('active')}
             };
            })
            }
```

my question is how can I highlight the item at the navigation bar that represents the section in view

Comment: What do you mean by highlighting?? Doesn't applying 'active' class highlights your item at the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply active class to only the item that matches the current section of the page. Try this: -

```
function isInView(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(rect.top > 70 && rect.top < 150){            //Assumed Y-offset for 1st section
        return element.id          //Assuming it returns 1 for 1st element
    }
    else if(rect.top > 150){
        return element.id          //Returns 2 for 2nd element
    }
   
};

function addActive() {
    document.addEventListener(
        "scroll",
        () => {

            for (section of sections) {
                if(isInView(section) == section.id){
                    section.classList.add('active')    //Only apply active class to this section
                }
                else{
                    section.classList.remove('active')  //Remove the active class from all other sections
                }
            };
               
            
            })
            }
```

Comment: it`s not highlighting the navigation bar item, it activates the section and my code already does that

Comment: @Mano Well your question is not clear. I've referred the 'active' class here as the style class that should be applied to your navbar's item when you are on the corresponding section of the page.
So you should style the active class for highlight effects like changing the background color of the item.
Or else provide a code on JSFiddle or Codepen to illustrate your purpose more clearly.